# How to port Swift code with unmanaged references to Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, porting

I was trying to port the following Swift code to Objective-C:

```
var contextImage: UIImage? = ... 
let image: CGImage? = contextImage?.cgImage
let dataProvider: CGDataProvider? = image?.dataProvider
let data: CFData? = dataProvider?.data
let baseAddress = CFDataGetBytePtr(data!)
contextImage = nil

let unmanagedData = Unmanaged<CFData>.passRetained(data!)
var pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer?
let status = CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(nil, 
                (image?.width)!, 
                (image?.height)!, 
                kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, 
                UnsafeMutableRawPointer( mutating: baseAddress!),
                (image?.bytesPerRow)!, 
                { releaseContext, baseAddress in
                    let contextData = Unmanaged<CFData>.fromOpaque(releaseContext!)
                    contextData.release()
                }, 
                unmanagedData.toOpaque(), 
                nil, 
                &pixelBuffer)
```

but I got stuck at the `Unmanaged` section and was not able to find the proper Objective-C way of doing that under `ARC` (the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unmanaged) of `Unmanaged` seems to exist only for Swift):

```
CGImageRef image = contextImage.CGImage;
CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGImageGetDataProvider(image);
CFDataRef data = CGDataProviderCopyData(dataProvider);
const UInt8 * baseAddress = CFDataGetBytePtr(data);
contextImage = nil;

// ... now what?
```

Eventually I accomplished it by integrating a Swift file into the Objective-C project but I still wonder, what is the proper way of porting that original Swift code in Objective-C?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need Unmanaged. Even in the Swift documentation for this function `RawPointers` are used.
This is how the documentation looks like for the ObjC.

```
CVReturn CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes (CFAllocatorRef allocator,
size_t width,
size_t height,
OSType pixelFormatType,
void *baseAddress,
size_t bytesPerRow,
CVPixelBufferReleaseBytesCallback releaseCallback,
void *releaseRefCon,
CFDictionaryRef pixelBufferAttributes,
CVPixelBufferRef *pixelBufferOut);
```

Its implementation could look something like this.

```
CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = NULL;
cvErr = CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
FRAME_WIDTH,
FRAME_HEIGHT,
kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA,
(void*)CFDataGetBytePtr(imageData),
CGImageGetBytesPerRow(image),
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
&pixelBuffer);
```

More in documentation for [CVPixelBufferCreate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1456979-cvpixelbuffercreatewithbytes?language=objc).